# How to disable touchpad completely on boot?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, systemd, synaptics, xinput

I wanted to disable touchpad before login on Ubuntu 16.10.

I had tried executing

```
#!/bin/bash

ID=$(/usr/bin/xinput list --id-only "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad")

if [[ $ID ]]; then
    /usr/bin/xinput --disable $ID
    echo "Touchpad disabled"
else
    echo "Touchpad not found"
fi
```

on boot with systemctl, rc.d, what not. Nothing seemed to work as it needed X running or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to 
`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/*-synaptics.conf`

```
# Disable generic Synaptics device, as we're using
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
        MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

Reboot and test if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I have Linux Mint 18 installed with kernel 4.4.0-45. I did the following to make it easy to toggle the touchpad state.

`sudo apt-get install xinput`

`xinput -list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ **FTE1001:00 0B05:0101**               ***id=14***   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

- Look for the id of the touchpad, in my case it's 14. I wrote a small shell script to turn the touchpad off and on.
- TouchPad off:

  `cd /usr/local/bin`
  `sudo nano touchpad-off`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # touchpad off
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0
  echo touchpad off
  ```
- TouchPad on:

  `sudo nano touchpad-on`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # touchpad on
  xinput --set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
  echo touchpad on
  ```
- Make the scripts executable with:

  ```
  chmod +x touchpad-off
  chmod +x touchpad-on
  ```

  Now you can easily toggle the touchpad state with `touchpad-off` and `touchpad-on` in your terminal.

**DISABLE ON BOOT:**
Go to Startup Applications and Add a new startup app, look for the script `touchpad-off` and add it to the list. You'll want to make sure the script is located in `usr/local/bin` as indicated above, as well as confirm it's executable.

Another thing to double check is making sure the file runs with Autorun Prompt. Right click on the file and go to the "Open With" tab, then select Autorun Prompt.

[Disable Touchpad on Boot Video Tutorial](https://youtu.be/SzRnqIvRfXc)

Comment: Unfortunately, the id number can change. In my case, it changes between 11 and 13.

Comment: @BobsonDugnutt you can combine it with the lookup solution used in the question: `xinput list --id-only "whatever the name of the device is on your system"`

Answer (score 0):

Since I run into it every time I buy a new Thinkpad, here is a somewhat more generalized method drawing from the other two responses:

1. find the name of the touchpad: `xinput --list`. You should get something like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 Elan TrackPoint                    id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA8022:00 06CB:CE67 Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA8022:00 06CB:CE67 Mouse               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

In my case the name to use will be `SYNA8022:00 06CB:CE67 Touchpad`

2. Test if that is actually the right device (and also spare yourself a reboot): `xinput --set-prop ID "Device Enabled" 0` , where ID is the ID from the list you got with the above command. If this disables the touchpad then you found the right ID and name
3. Create a file in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` call it e.g. `20_synaptics.conf` (the number defines the order with regards to the other files, as usual):

```
# Disable touchpad
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
        MatchProduct "SYNA8022:00 06CB:CE67 Touchpad"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```

The MatchProduct string should be the one you found in the xinput list.

4. To test if it works switch to a text console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 (or try other numbers if console 3 is already taken). Log in then start an X session: `sudo xinit -- :2`. This will start a second X server without rebooting your machine. You'll probably just see a single terminal window (without a border, because you won't have a window manager running) but it's enough to test if the touch pad is disabled. You can exit by typing Ctrl+D into the terminal window.